# how to start mysql server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, mysql

I have Ubuntu installed via WSL 2 like so:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

I'm trying to install mysql-server with this command, 'sudo apt install mysql-server'

(https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-mysql)

I get it installed with

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

but it does not start after that.

```
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo service mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld

(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo service mysql restart                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory
```

I have tried a set of these commands:

this one is to change the home directory.

```
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
usermod: user mysql is currently used by process 3622
```

```
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
usermod: user mysql is currently used by process 3622
(base) bluetail14@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

So it looks like I need to configure a home directory from nonexistent or something else?
how can I set it up correctly?

Comment: Your `mysql` system seems to be running. As you're working in WSL, you can't use `systemd` commands such as `systemctl`. Instead, use `sudo service mysql stop` (and start, and restart, and status) for managing MySQL. Please don't change the default location of MySQL directories unless you know very well what you are doing.

Comment: thank you. it helps. I used 'sudo service mysql status' and it does not throw any errors.